# jquery ui button icon change dynamically

Tags: jquery

```
$("#slideshowadvanceconfig").button({
icons:{ primary: 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-e'} }).toggle(function () { 
$(this).button("option", { icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-s'} });    

$(".settings").slideDown('slow'); }, 
function () { $(this).button("option", { icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-e'} });

$(".settings").slideUp('slow'); 
});
```

Through this above code i am trying to change the icon of jquery ui button dynamically. Slideup and SlideDown works but image is not changing , can anybody tell me the problem?

Comment: show your html markup, or even it better if u create a JSfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see you are targeting the icons: value after the page is drawn, you will need to target the src value of the html image element to change it programmaticly

Comment: i want to change icon (east arrow to south arrow and vice versa)